# Disabling all html tags, except some tags I want to allow

Tags: php, html, tags

I want to allow tags like `<b>, <h1>, <h2>` but still disabling HTML in posts.
How can I do that? can I do it with htmlspecialchars?

Thanks for your help , The site and the users are really helpful :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use strip_tags http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php the second arguments allows some tags.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for, I forgot about that function :)

Comment: for the color, you can use preg_replace and capturing parenthesis. `$new_string = preg_replace('<font style="(\\#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})">','the font is $1',$your_string);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `strip_tags()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$stripped = strip_tags($text, "<b><h1><h2>");
```

Caveat emptor. There might be some security implications there.

Comment: I researched a little bit. `strip_tags()` seems to be good in preventing attacks. See for example: http://shiflett.org/articles/foiling-cross-site-attacks, where `strip_tags()`is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool called HTML Purifier that does exactly what you are asking for :)  You should check it out: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Another alternative is to use BBCode which can be found here: http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/

Good luck :D

Comment: I'm using a text editor in PHPBB and I don't need BBCODES, Thanks for the Information. But I'll need a php function.

Comment: Why can't you use an external library?  Trying to do something like this yourself poses a LOT of security risks.  It's very easy to get through basic security systems like this which is why it is generally better to use an open source solution which will be fixed when holes are found.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I secure it :)

Comment: Good luck is all i can say :)  I hope you are more clever than the hackers :)

Comment: Well I am one (White Hat ofc) :) and Thanks.